# show the description when hover the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this HTML :

```
<div class="left_area">
 <div class="caption"> 
   <a href="<?php echo $URL; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $images; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a>
   <span>test</span></div>
</div>
```

i want when i go over the image with the mouse to display whatever i want in that span, even an image of a but button or bold text. something like this [EXAMPLE](http://www.bensoutlet.com/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F6p2Z/2/)

***CSS***

```css
.caption {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

***JS***

```
$('.caption').on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(this).find('span').fadeIn(200);
    },

    mouseout: function() {
        $(this).find('span').stop().fadeOut(200);
    },
})
```

Comment: yes, like this, but want the text to be on the image can it be done?

Comment: yes, it's working in jsfidlle, but i can't figure out why is not showing for me, i think it's hiding behind the image somehow

Comment: and it's making caption on the text not on all the image, the background is working for the text not the image

Comment: Nobody can give you the *exact* code you want because only you know what do you need to have as the outcome. This is just a rough working idea which you can build on and alter it according to your needs

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a','.caption').mouseenter(function(){
     $('span',$(this).parent()).show();
  }).mouseleave(function(){
     $('span',$(this).parent()).hide();
  });
```

});​

reference  http://jsfiddle.net/puu5u/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS

#### HTML

```
​<div class="image">
<p class="caption">Some info related the pic</p>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/VMaxsb.jpg" />
</div>​
```

#### CSS

```
.image {float: left; position: relative;}
.image .caption {width: 100%; height: 100%; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.82); position: absolute; color: #fff; display: none}
.image:hover​ .caption {display: block;}​
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/hqLjz/

Comment: sorry i see no results in jsfiddle

Comment: @Jimmy: it appears that his image isn't being pulled from imgur.  But if you hover over the broken image icon, it should be replace by a black box with text from the `<p>` element.

Comment: @Jimmy - open this image once http://i.imgur.com/VMaxsb.jpg then open the fiddle. Imgur has some problem with jsfiddle

Comment: yes, correct, is working, how can i work with the text " Some info related the pic" i need it to be displayed at the bottom maybe, i mean how can i control it at all ?

Comment: Position can be set using top,left,right and bottom CSS attributes for .image .caption, whereas the text can be edited in HTML directly

Comment: please update you code so the text is showing at the bottom for example because i don't believe it can be done, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ul li').mouseenter(function(){
    var image= $(this).find('img'),
        caption = $(this).find('div');

    caption.width(image.width());
    caption.height(image.height());
    caption.fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
     var image= $(this).find('img'),
        caption = $(this).find('div');

    caption.width(image.width());
    caption.height(image.height());
    caption.fadeOut();
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVvND/)